# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) when using void()

Tags: javascript

I get this error and I've managed to narrow it down to:

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="myFunction();">aaa</a>
```

That line of code is now the only thing in my source code and still I get the error in title. Any idea why so?

Even when surrounded with the appropriate HTML elements (html, head, body etc) I am still thrown the error. The error shows up in Chrome dev console and via alert if I include a

```
window.onerror
```

function in the head tag. It also occurs when the `myFunction()` method actually exists. As far as I can gather, there is absolutely nothing wrong with that above statement whatsoever.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction();">aaa</a>
```

[void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void#syntax) expects a parameter.

There's an interesting discussion on using `void(0)` or other techniques [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0).

Answer (score 4):

Is because void [takes one argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void).
You want:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction();">aaa</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

`void` is an operator, not a function. It requires a single expression as its operand. `()` is not a valid expression. The correct syntax is:

```
<a href="javascript:void 0;" onclick="myFunction();">aaa</a>
```

You can put parentheses around `0`, but they're not necessary, just as you don't need parentheses around `0` when writing `3 + 0`.